# Is this a static method, or something else?

Tags: dart

I'm learning Dart so that I can do some flutter mobile development.  Dart's pretty straightforward to learn and I like it, though there are a few differences from Java / C# that I have to work through.

One of them has to do with this code:

```
class CatalogSlice {

  final List<CatalogPage> _pages;

  final int startIndex;

  final bool hasNext;

  CatalogSlice(this._pages, this.hasNext)
      : startIndex = _pages.map((p) => p.startIndex).fold(0x7FFFFFFF, min);

  const CatalogSlice.empty()
      : _pages = const [],
        startIndex = 0,
        hasNext = true;
}
```

Ignoring all the business-specific stuff in there about what a `CatalogSlice` represents, I'm confused about the definition of the `empty()` method.  Is that a static, class method, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [named constructor](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors). You call it the same way you call the generative constructor.

```
var instance1 = new CatalogSlice(pages, hasNext);
var instance2 = new CatalogSlice.empty();
```

Dart doesn't have method/constructor overloading ([yet](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26488)) and that's why they introduced this feature.